# Find out a Java class file's compiler version

Tags: compilers, java

I have a java class file. How do I find out the version of the compiler used to compile this file? I'm on Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The JDK includes a `javap` command. It gives a lot information, but you can use it like this:

```
javap -verbose yourClass | grep version
```

Example output:

```
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
```

The major version tells you which version the compiler had:

```
J2SE 8 = 52,
J2SE 7 = 51,
J2SE 6.0 = 50,
J2SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

Comment: for 45, the exact compiler version depends on the minor version. 45.3 would be 1.0.2 I beleive.

Comment: This actually tells you the version of the class file format, not the version of the compiler or other tool used to generate it. `javac` supports the `-target` or `--release` flag to generate class files targeted at earlier versions of the JDK.

Comment: Is there a way to get the version but in the code ?

Answer (score 15):

Again the [`file(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) utility and [`libmagic(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic), on which it is based, can be your friend:

```
$ file Gwan.class
Gwan.class: compiled Java class data, version 50.0 (Java 1.6)
```

Comment: What if you're on Windows?

Comment: @avgvstvs: then you can still resort to something like Cygwin. Honestly, if you limit your own toolset by restricting your RCE efforts to a single host OS, that's your own fault. Simply put: know what tools to use when and don't be picky based on arbitrary and artificial limitations.

Comment: Cygwin introduces an unnecessary dependency.  If you're reversing *.class files, on *every* JVM you're going to have access to `javap`.  I don't disagree with the rest of what you're saying, but I'm lazy and if I don't have to start a vm or d/l cygwin I'm happier.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this on the command line (for a class called MyClass):

On Unix/Linux:

```
javap -verbose MyClass | grep "major"
```

On Windows:

```
javap -verbose MyClass | findstr "major"
```

You want the major version from the results. Here are some example values:

- Java 1.2 uses major version 46
- Java 1.3 uses major version 47
- Java 1.4 uses major version 48
- Java 5 uses major version 49
- Java 6 uses major version 50
- Java 7 uses major version 51
- Java 8 uses major version 52